# Add custom sharepoint 2010 notification

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 and I need to add custom notification such as send fax in a sharepoint workflow , but I searched and nothing find how to write a program with C# or Vb.Net  for how to adding new notification to sharepoint designer.I want add my notification to sharepoint designer too for using by sharepoint users.
Any help (or even just a link or example) are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an article for 2007, guess it should also work for 2010:

Building Custom Activities for Use in SharePoint Designer 2007
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629922(v=office.12).aspx